# TP Link TL-wn722n (AR9271 Chipset) not working

Tags: wireless, usb

I am trying to get my TL-WN722N V2 (EU) AR9271 USB wireless adapter working on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I cannot find a current driver that supports my kernal (4.4) or version of Ubuntu 16.04.02. First off, the adapter is recognized with the lsusb command as 0cf3:9271, but no further information. lsusb -t has a (=,) and does not give me any further driver information.

Through older posts on Ask Ubuntu, I have tried installing the driver through  backports  3.16-1, but it does not work. If any further info is needed please let me know. Really would appreciate help on this.

Comment: This is a question for Chili555 or Pilot6

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `usb-devices | awk '/0cf3/' RS=` terminal command.

Comment: This adapter is supported by the 4.4 kernel out of the box. You do not need any drivers.

Comment: What happens with `sudo modprobe -v ath9k_htc`

Comment: Pilot , I will get the output later today. For now, the card is not Plug n play, at least for me. The sudo modprobe -v ath9k_htc returned nothing, it just jumps to the next line with no output. Does anyone know a Debian distribution that will work for sure with it as plug n play?

Comment: Ok, lsusb output was actually BUS 002 Device 007: ID 2357:010c and the sudo modprobe -v ath9k_htc output was: command not found.

Comment: usb-devices | awk '/2357 RS= T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2357 ProdID=010c Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n NIC
S:  SerialNumber=00E04C0001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)

Comment: and Kernel version is 4.8.0-36 Generic

Comment: Please show us the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe ath9k_htc` and also: `dmesg | grep ath`